# How does the Offer Quantity and Inventory Quantity change?

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I am trying to create an Inventory Management application using the Ebay Sell APIs. When adding a product, I first add some quantity (say 100 T-Shirts) to the Inventory. Next, I make this inventory live by creating an offer and specifying the offer quantity (say 10 T-Shirts).

Now, my question is, when there is a successful sale of some of the inventory via an offer, does either of the offer quantity or inventory quantity change automatically? Or do I have to manually call [bulkUpdatePriceQuantity](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/inventory_item/methods/bulkUpdatePriceQuantity) to update the quantities?

*PS: I would test this myself on the sandbox, however, I am unable to fetch orders due to some internal error on the eBay APIs*